# check interpolation value is empty or not in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have loop with one conditions. if the IF condition is false data is not binded, but i want to bind some value if interpolation value is empty.

```
<span v-for="pai in paid">
       <b v-if="pai.bill_no==report.bill_no" >
            {{ +pai.paid + report.paid==='' ? (+pai.paid + report.paid) : data  }}
        </b>    
</span>
```

Here data variable is not printing when value is empty.
How can i print this if condition is false and inerpolation value is empty?

Comment: which condition ? unclear what you are saying ?

Comment: <b v-if="pai.bill_no==report.bill_no" >   if this condition is true it prints the string inrteropolation value if the condition is false nothing prints. but i want tp print something when value is empty

Comment: Use `v-else` as I anserwed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`v-else` directive](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-else)

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    paid:[
      {bill_no:1},
      {bill_no:2},
      {bill_no:3},
    ],
    report:{bill_no:2}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="pai in paid">
       <b v-if="pai.bill_no==report.bill_no" >
            {{ +pai.paid + report.paid==='' ? (+pai.paid + report.paid) : 'data'  }}
        </b>    
        <b v-else>Something else</b>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actualy yur code should work but actualy in my case its not wotking because <div for="bills in bills"> <div v-for="pai in paid"> i have 2 loops. so it goes to else part everytime

Comment: can you share your actual code ? so that it is clear ?

Comment: `<ul>
                <li v-for="report in reportBill"> <div class="col-md-2">{{report.bill_no}}</div> <span class="">Total Amount: <b>{{report.total_amount}} </b></span>
                                    <!--<h6>Paid : <b>{{200}}</b></h6>-->

                                   Paid  <span v-for="pai in paid">
                                    <b v-if="pai.bill_no==report.bill_no" >
                                        {{ pai.paid + report.paid ? (+pai.paid + report.paid) : report.paid  }}
                                    </b>
                                </span>`